# Set-builder notation for vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have $\Bbb{R}^3$ domain, so it's a 3-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system with $x, y, z$ axes. I need to define a set in this domain that contains only vectors $\mathbf{v}$ that consists of components $v_x, v_y, v_z$ with limitations:
$$ x_{min} < v_x < x_{max}; y_{min} < v_y < y_{max}; z_{min} < v_z < z_{max}. $$

I've started with $S = \{\mathbf{v} \in \Bbb{R}^3 | x_{min} < v_x < x_{max}, y_{min} < v_y < y_{max}, z_{min} < v_z < z_{max}\}$

I don't think it's correct. Also, it's a very long string. What if I need to define set in $\Bbb{R}^{10}$?

How to define the set?

P.S. Feel free to point out to my another mistakes in defining problem.

Comment: This is correct. If you want shorter notation define $\mathbf{v}_{\min}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{\max}$ with components given by your bounds and write $S = \{\mathbf{v} \in \Bbb{R}^3 | \mathbf{v}_{\min}<\mathbf{v}<\mathbf{v}_{\max}\}$, where the inequalities use the [componentwise order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order) on $\Bbb{R}^3$ or $ \Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to use subscripts: if we write $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then  $S=\{\mathbf{v} |m_i\leq v_i\leq M_i,1\leq i\leq 3\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is correct.

A shorter way to write it would be
$$S=[x_{\rm min},x_{\rm max}]\times[y_{\rm min},y_{\rm max}]\times[z_{\rm min},z_{\rm max}]$$

For a vector in $\mathbb R^{10}$ you might go for
$$ S = \prod_{n=1}^{10} [x_{n,\rm min},x_{n,\rm max}] $$

If all lower/upper limits are the same, then you can also use a notation like
$$ S = [x_{\rm min},x_{\rm max}]^3 $$